# Android: Sqlite rawQuery out of range

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to use a rawQuery with a simpleCursorAdapter to display to a listview, but it keeps throwing me an error

> 04-29 13:36:36.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29539): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.QuoteMachine/com.QuoteMachine.Quote}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x2f65e0

I have a table called Quotes with columns _id, auth_name, quote, category and my query looks as follows

```
return qmDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id as _id, auth_name, quote, category FROM Quotes",
            new String[]{"WHERE auth_name = 'Robert Anton Wilson'"});
```

Might anyone know of a suggestion to fix this problem?My original plan was to use a basic query statement, but there was a problem with column _id and it was suggested I go with this approach.

Answer (score 4):

Your using the rawQuery() wrong. The second variable is for the arguments, not for the WHERE clause. Use that instead:

```
return qmDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id as _id, auth_name, quote, category FROM Quotes WHERE auth_name = ?",
            new String[] { "Robert Anton Wilson" } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly confusion with the quote() function?  One of your columns is called 'quote'.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: I see what you mean but the word is not used in the context of a function, nor containing any parameters while also in a string selection of "", so this is not the problem.Thanks for the suggestion though :)